# Erro ao utilizar horário local como condição

Tags: java, data

Este método eu utilizo para validar a entrada de um aluno, e não está rodando.
A ideia é utilizar o horário local para validar a entrada de um aluno. Se ele for do  ensino médio, poderá entrar apenas nos horários entre às 7 horas até às 12 horas, se for fundamental II, irá ingressar a partir das 13 até às 18 horas.

```
public String horario() {
    String d;
    String j;
    Date dataHoraAtual = new Date();
    String hora = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(dataHoraAtual);
    j = hora;
    String g = j.substring(0,1);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(g);
    if(b>=7 && b<=12){
        j="ddd";
    }else{
        if(b>=13 && b<=18){
            j = "Fundamental";
        }
    }
    
    return j;
}
```

Mesmo convertendo a variável de `String` para `int`, a variável `j` não está sendo modificada e mesmo eu colocando outra variável em seu lugar para retornar a mensagem, ocorre um erro no `return`.

Mesmo utilizando esta linha de código:

```
int b = Integer.parseInt(g.substring(0, 1));
```

Não encontrei alguma resolução para isso. O que me retorna ainda é o horário local, como se a varíavel `j` não tivesse sido modificada.

Comment: Arthur para pegar os 2 dígitos da hora precisa mudar o substring: `j.substring(0,2);`

Comment: Olá Ricardo, poxaaa,muito obrigadooooo!!. Olha, vou te contar cara , algo tão simples ajudou muito. Te agradeço de coração e obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Na verdade você está fazendo uma volta desnecessária, transformando a data em string para depois converter pedaços da string para número. Se estiver usando Java >= 8, dê uma olhada na classe `java.time.LocalTime`, e para versões anteriores, use `java.util.Calendar` em vez de `Date` - com essas classes você consegue obter os valores numéricos da hora e minuto diretamente (ou até comparar direto com outra data) - procure por exemplos aqui no site mesmo que tem vários

Answer (score 0):

Você está fazendo uma volta desnecessária, convertendo a data para string e depois pegando pedaços da string e convertendo para número.

Não precisa de nada disso, os objetos de data e hora já possuem métodos para obter os valores numéricos e para comparar com outras datas.

Outro detalhe é que não ficou claro o que fazer com os minutos. Por exemplo, o retorno "ddd" deve ser quando o horário está entre 7 e 12, mas e os minutos? Se for 12:30, é "ddd" ou não? Resumindo, deve ser entre 07:00 e 12:00, ou entre 07:00 e 12:59? O mesmo vale para o "Fundamental", é até as 18:00 ou 18:59? Pela forma que você fez, entendo que provavelmente é até os 59 minutos (pelo menos é assim que sua lógica funcionaria).

De qualquer forma, dá para fazer mais simples. Se estiver usando Java >= 8, use a [API `java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). Como você só está interessado no horário (independente do dia), pode usar um [`java.time.LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html):

```
public String horario() {
    // horário atual
    LocalTime agora = LocalTime.now();
    // verifica se está entre 07:00 e 12:59
    if (!LocalTime.of(7, 0).isAfter(agora) && agora.isBefore(LocalTime.of(13, 0))) {
        return "ddd";
    }
    // verifica se está entre 13:00 e 18:59
    if (!LocalTime.of(13, 0).isAfter(agora) && agora.isBefore(LocalTime.of(19, 0))) {
        return "Fundamental";
    }
    // se não está em nenhum dos intervalos acima, é inválido
    return "horário inválido";
}
```

Para o horário inicial, usei `! ... isAfter` ("se não é depois"), pois o horário inicial pode ser anterior à hora atual, ou igual (se for examente 07:00, cai no "ddd"). Já para o horário final, fiz apenas `agora.isBefore(...)` ("horário atual é antes de"). Por exemplo, para "ddd", a hora atual deve estar antes de 13:00, o que quer dizer que se for até 12:59:59.999999999 ele será "ddd" (se for 13:00 já não entra neste `if`).

Claro que também poderia ser assim:

```
public String horario() {
    // horário atual
    int hora = LocalTime.now().getHour();
    if (7 <= hora && hora <= 12) {
        return "ddd";
    }
    if (13 <= hora && hora <= 18) {
        return "Fundamental";
    }
    return "horário inválido";
}
```

Mas a primeira opção é mais flexível, por permitir quaisquer combinação de horas e minutos. Por exemplo, se o horário de saída for 18:30, é mais simples mudar o primeiro código, bastando trocar o `LocalTime.of(19, 0)` pelo valor que quiser. Já usando o segundo código, você teria que obter os minutos e colocar mais uma condição no `if`.

---

Para Java <= 7, uma opção é usar `java.util.Calendar`. A diferença é que é um pouco mais chato criar uma instãncia com um horário específico (no caso abaixo, criei um método para isso):

```
public String horario() {
    // horário atual
    Calendar agora = Calendar.getInstance();
    // verifica se está entre 07:00 e 12:59
    if (criarComHorario(7, 0).compareTo(agora) <= 0 && agora.compareTo(criarComHorario(13, 0)) < 0) {
        return "ddd";
    }
    // verifica se está entre 13:00 e 18:59
    if (criarComHorario(13, 0).compareTo(agora) <= 0 && agora.compareTo(criarComHorario(19, 0)) < 0) {
        return "Fundamental";
    }
    return "horário inválido";
}

private Calendar criarComHorario(int hora, int minuto) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hora);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuto);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return cal;
}
```

Ou, se quiser a opção menos flexível, que compara apenas o valor do horário:

```
public String horario() {
    // horário atual
    Calendar agora = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hora = agora.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    if (7 <= hora && hora <= 12) {
        return "ddd";
    }
    if (13 <= hora && hora <= 18) {
        return "Fundamental";
    }
    return "horário inválido";
}
```

---

Obs: você até poderia usar os *getters* e *setters* de `Date`, mas eles estão *deprecated* desde o Java 1.1 então prefira usar `Calendar` (mas apenas se não estiver usando Java >= 8, claro, pois neste caso, prefira usar o `java.time`).